# python for loop calculation too inefficient/long

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, calculation

I am running a back-testing program on python. However, even though the maths/logic is simple, python seems to be taking an extremely long time to calculate the FOR loop.

For each row/line, it takes on average 1-sec; and when I have thousands to potentially ten-of-thousands of rows-of-data, the time-taken is impractical.

I use a panda dataframe as the base, and generate forward calculations by for-loop. Is there a more efficient way, or what could I do to reduce the computational time?

```
def signal_TA1(data, periods):
    columns = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', .......]
    pd_Append = pd.DataFrame((np.zeros((len(data.index),len(columns)))), columns = columns) #create and initialize as zeros needed columns
    data = data.join(pd_Append)
    data['Size'] = data.bidQ + data.askQ
    data['prx'] = (data.bid * data.askQ + data.ask * data.bidQ)/data.Size

    for i in range(1, len(data.index), 1):
        data.emaX.iloc[i] = data.lambda_.iloc[i] * data.Size.iloc[i] + (1 - data.lambda_.iloc[i]) * data.emaX.iloc[i-1]
        xxxxxx
        xxxxx
        xxxxx
    return data
```

Comment: Please share an example of your dataframe and the desired output. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Comment: Then instead to loop on `range(1, len(data.index), 1)` you could use `for _, row  in data.iterrows()`

Comment: Indeed. I think retrieving the value with `iloc[i]` multiple times is a bottleneck and can be removed like this. Also, instead of retrieving the previous calculated value with `iloc[i-1]`, you can save the calculated value in a variable for use for the next loop.

Comment: I'll try to add more details. But in the interim, why I don't use a re-use set of variables, is because I need to check the behaviour of the output and intermediate values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems (well, it seems to be relatively known) that numpy processes looped calculations much more effectively than pandas (as it has to re-built the whole array each time).

Basically, I create a numpy array [x,y] within the function. Then, I calculate via a for-loop and populate the numpy array, row-by-row. Finally, I merely convert the finished numpy array into a pandas dataframe (for easier display and plotting).
The time difference is forever versus < 1 second for about 2,500 rows of data-and-calculation.

```
def signal_M2(data, weight, pandas = True):
    bid = np.array(data.bid)
    ask = np.array(data.ask)
    askQ = np.array(data.askQ)
    bidQ = np.array(data.bidQ)
    size = bidQ + askQ
    VWAP = (bid * askQ + ask * bidQ)/(bidQ + askQ)

    columns = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, .....]
    datB = np.zeros((len(data.index), len(columns)))
    datA = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns = columns)

    lambda_ = 0.5
    weight = 0.3
    x1 = VWAP[0]
    x2 = VWAP[0]
    x3 = VWAP[0]
    x4 = VWAP[0]
    x5 = size[0]
    ....
    ....
    datB[0] = (bid[0], ask[0], bidQ[0], askQ[0], size[0], ..........)

    for row in range(1, len(data.index), 1):
        x1 = lambda_ * size[row] + (1 - lambda_) * emaInertia
        x2 = weight * VWAP[row] + (1 - weight) * emaPrx
        x3 = weight * VWAP[row] + (1 -weight) * emaPrxSlow
        x4 = weight * VWAP[row] + (1 -weight) * emaPrxFast
        x5 = weight * VWAP[row] + (1 -weight) * emaPrxLead

        if pandas == True:
            datB[row] = (bid[row], ask[row], bidQ[row], ...........)
        else:
            print(................)

    if pandas == True:
        datB = pd.DataFrame(datB, columns = columns)
        return datB 
    else : 
        print('no pandas dataframe was asked to be be stored')
```